# Cutoff function in the proof of inner regularity of Poisson equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

In chapter 11 of Jost partial differential equations he wants to prove the following theorem of interior regularity for the Poisson equation:

> **Theorem 11.2.1**: Let $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ be a weak solution of $\Delta u=f$, with $f\in L^2(\Omega)$. For any $\Omega'\subset\subset\Omega$, then $u\in W^{2,2}(\Omega')$ and
> $$\lVert u \rVert_{W_{2,2}(\Omega')}\leq const(\lVert u \rVert_{L_2(\Omega)}+\lVert f \rVert_{L_2(\Omega)})$$

where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open domain. To prove this theorem he uses this cutoff function:
$$\eta(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        1 & x \in \Omega'\\
        0 & d(x,\Omega')\geq \delta\\
        1-\frac{1}{\delta}d(x,\Omega') & 0\leq d(x,\Omega')\leq \delta
    \end{cases}$$
where $\delta=d(\Omega',\partial \Omega)$. It is easy to prove that $\eta$ satisfies the following properties:

- $0\leq \eta \leq 1$
- $\eta=1$ on $\Omega'$
- $\eta\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$
- $\lvert \nabla\eta\rvert\leq \frac{2}{\delta}$

Then he takes $v=\eta^2 u$ and he plugs it in the definition of weak solution:
$$\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v=-\int_\Omega fv \qquad \forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)=W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$$
I cannot see why $v=\eta^2 u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. I know that $\eta, u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, but $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is not an algebra.

I know that I can take a $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ cutoff function using mollifications, but I would like to understand why we can use this simpler cutoff function.

Thank you

Edit: Since $\eta$ is lipschitz $\eta\in W^{1,\infty}_0(\Omega)$. Now from this lemma ([Differentiation of a product of Sobolev functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295500/differentiation-of-a-product-of-sobolev-functions)) I deduce that also $\eta^2\in W^{1,\infty}_0(\Omega)$. I don't know if it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you have more information about $\eta$ than just the fact that it is in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. Applying the product rule, we have
\begin{align}
|\nabla(\eta^2 u)| =& |2 \eta u \nabla \eta  + \eta^2 \nabla u |\\
\leq & 2| \eta| |u|| \nabla \eta| + |\eta|^2| \nabla u | \\
\leq &  \frac{4}{\delta}|u| + |\nabla u|  \, .
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{equation}
\int_\Omega|\nabla(\eta^2 u)|^2 \leq  C \lVert u \rVert_{H^1_0(\Omega)}^2 \, ,
\end{equation}
for some constant $C$ dependent on $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know why I can apply the product rule in this case. All the versions I know have stronger hypothesis. In other words I think I miss a theorem like: if $f,g\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $(\nabla f) g+f(\nabla g)\in L^2(\Omega)$ then $fg\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ e $\nabla (fg)= (\nabla f) g+f(\nabla g)$

Comment: You can see that this holds true by mollifying $f$ and $g$ applying the product rule and passing to the limit.